# if has bad state return something else Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have a method in my controller that calculates me how many values I have in total

```
  get gesamtAnzahl => _products.entries
  .map((product) => product.value)
  .toList()
  .reduce((value, element) => value + element)
  .toStringAsFixed(2);
```

the problem is that I get each product pretty late
So it has a bad state when I try to calculate these values at a time where no product exists

I tried doing something like this

```
"${controller.gesamtAnzahl == null ? "0" : controller.gesamtAnzahl}"
```

but I still get the bad state: no element error

what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that [`reduce`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-core/Iterable/reduce.html) wants at least one element. If you don't have any elements it will therefore fail. You could instead use [`fold`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-core/Iterable/fold.html) which have a starting value that can be returned in case no elements are found.

There are also some other questionable code in your example but something like this should work:

```dart
  get gesamtAnzahl => _products.values
  .fold<int>(0, (value, element) => value + element)
  .toStringAsFixed(2);
```

Should be noted that this would only work if you actually wants `"0.00"` to be returned in case `_products` are empty.

Comment: yes I want exactly that! Thank you, never heard of fold before crazy :D

Comment: @Nikita I recommend taking a look at the methods in the `Iterable` class. There are not that many and it is useful to memorize what is available here: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-core/Iterable-class.html :)

Comment: Will do that :) thank you!